# a simple question about compositions of functions

Tags: functions

If $f(v) = \frac{1}{v^2 + 5}$ and $g(v) = \sqrt{v+4}$, how do you find $g \circ f$? Please provide steps.

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 1):

By definition and *guessing* that $\;f(v)=\frac1{v^2+5}\;$:

$$g\circ f(v)= g(f(v))=g\left(\frac1{v^2+5}\right)=\sqrt{\frac1{v^2+5}+4}=\sqrt{\frac{4v^2+21}{v^2+5}}$$

Comment: The answer is correct indeed, but how did you get the numerator? "4v^2+21"

Comment: Fractions sum, @JayFJ: $$\frac1{v^2+5}+4=\frac{1+4(v^2+5)}{v^2+5}=\frac{4v^2+21}{v^2+5}$$